# How to assign at least 1 pod on every node in a node group

Tags: kubernetes

We have a node group, each node within the group has the same label `acme/node-type: worker`. This node group has 2 nodes in it and they are spot instances.

We have a deployment that has 3 replicas that live on this node group. We have implemented this using `nodeAffinity`

```
spec:
  affinity:
   nodeAffinity:
     requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
       nodeSelectorTerms:
       - matchExpressions:
         - key: acme/node-type
           operator: In
           values:
           - worker
```

We have noticed a problem when a spot instance gets relcaimed, all of the pods  move over to the 2nd node. Its not ideal having all of the pods running on one node where there are 2 available. We want the 3 replica deployment to be spread across the 2 nodes.

We want there to be **atleast** 1 pod on every node within the node group. Is this possible?

Attempt1:

```
   topologySpreadConstraints:
      - maxSkew: 1
        topologyKey: acme/node-type
        whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
        labelSelector:
          matchLabels:
            acme/node-type: worker
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to configure [topology spread constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/)

with `whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway`

Also consider using [descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler) which helps to make best decision when removing node

Comment: Hi i updated my question with attempt of using topologySpreradConstraint, although it did not turn out how i expected (atleast 1 pod on each node in the node group). Although im not entirely familiar, what could i be doing  wrong?